# Escaping a Single Quote inside the string in Powershell

Tags: python, powershell

I have this particular string `abc'dsq` which has a single quote inside it and causing an issue. can you help me escape this string so that it gets passed align with the single quotes

I tried `,\,',""` nothing works

Comment: You need to be more specific, tried with what? powershell or python? what command or operator did you try? whats the expected result?

Comment: did you try double single quotes to create a single quote by chance?

Comment: It is not clear where you are using this parameter and or how python is involved, but you might try to see if this worked as you expected `-jW!<>!26''R4]3yq`

Answer (score 2):

Python and PowerShell both support `"..."` (double-quoted) and `'...'` (single-quoted) string literals.

- **Inside `"..."`, `'` quotes do NOT require escaping** in *either* environment; e.g., `"6' tall"`

  - **Only `"` quotes require escaping inside `"..."`**, and the escaping methods differ between these two environments, as they do for `'` inside `'...'` (see below):

    - In Python, use `\"`
    - In PowerShell, use `` `" `` (or `""`).
  - Note that - unlike in Python - PowerShell's `"..."` strings have *different semantics*: they are *expandable* (support *string interpolation*) - see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings).
- **Inside `'...'`**, the **escaping methods** differ:

  - In **Python**, `'` must be escaped as **`\'`**
  - In **PowerShell**, `'` must be escaped as **`''`**